# How to filter out specific repos when filtering Github pull requests

Tags: github, pull-request

I admin a few Github organisations and 1 in particular has 119 repos - From the 119 repos, there are 4 I am not interested in when it comes to open pull requests.

I am trying to figure out how I can use the pull request filter so these are not shown.
My current filter to show all open pull requests is:
 is:open is:pr user: sort:created 
And I can amend to show for a particular repo or repos:
 is:open is:pr repo:/ repo:/ sort:created

Does anyone know how I can filter to show all repos EXCEPT the ones I am not interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-` to exclude subsets :

```
org:Google  is:open repo:is:pr -repo:google/ggrc-core -repo:google/protobuf
```

Check : https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/#filter-qualifiers-based-on-exclusion

Comment: Perfect!  That's solved it and thanks for the link too Bertrand